# If f(n) is O(g(n)) and g(n) is O(h(n)) how can I prove that f(n) + g(n) is O(h(n))?

Tags: time-complexity

I understand that f(n) is less than or equal to a constant times g(n) for all n greater than or equal to k where n and c are positive. I also understand the same for g(n) and how it is of O(h(n)). However, I am unsure how f(n) + g(n) is of O(h(n)).

Comment: One strategy: 1) Prove `f(n)` is `O(h(n))`. Then 2) Prove that if two functions are `O(h(n))` then so is their sum.

Comment: Use the definitions given to you.